# Neither Binding result nor plain target for bean name user available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. When I try to open JSP page I am getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.RegisterUser_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(RegisterUser_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.RegisterUser_jsp._jspService(RegisterUser_jsp.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
25 Jun, 2015 5:54:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Banking] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.RegisterUser_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(RegisterUser_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.RegisterUser_jsp._jspService(RegisterUser_jsp.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code:

RegisterUser.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Register User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form   commandName="user">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td> <input type="Submit" id="submitBtn" value="Post"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p >
        <%
            if(request.getAttribute("errorMessage") != null)
            {
                out.println(request.getAttribute("errorMessage"));
            }

        %>
    </p>    
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

UserController.java

```
package com.krishnaja.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.krishnaja.entity.User;
import com.krishnaja.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(){}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUSer(@ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result)
    {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/index.jsp";
    }


}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.krishnaja.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.krishnaja.dao.UserDao;
import com.krishnaja.entity.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(User user)
    {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<User> retrieveAllUsers()
    {
        return userDao.retrieveAllUsers();
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd"
    >


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.krishnaja.controller"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.krishnaja.dao"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.krishnaja.service"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.krishnaja.entity"/> 
    <bean id="user" class="com.krishnaja.controller.UserController"></bean>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="resources/user.properties" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller method to :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUSer(@ModelAttribute("user")User user, Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        if(user.getUsername().isEmpty()){
            return "redirect:/";
        } else{
        userService.saveUser(user);
         }
        return "redirect:/index.jsp";
    }
```

If it doesnt work, let me know, I have some other suggestions.

*Update*

Change your JSP body to :

```
<body>
<c:url var="addAction" value="/" ></c:url>
    <form:form action="${addAction}"  commandName="user">
    <table>

 <c:if test="${!empty user.Username}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="userid">
                        <spring:message text="userid"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="userid" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="userid" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>  <c:if test="${empty user.Username}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add User"/>" />
                </c:if>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
```

The userId in JSP is the unique key which you are planning to save. If your model is correct, this will work. I would not call the registration method at landing page so horribly, but your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I added model.addAttribute like ModelMap model = new ModelMap();model.addAttribute("user", new User()) ; Is this correct? if so it is still not working

Comment: No, I didn't meant ModelMap, I just meant Model, please check the updated controller method. Use that, notice, there is an input parameter Model, don't worry, you dont need to change anything in JSP for that parameter.

Comment: I have edited my answer to change your controller as well as your JSP. Even if this will work, I would suggest you read more about Spring, JSP's.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because you haven't add model object that's why this exception has been thrown.

try to add in Controller

```
model.addObject("user", user);
```

and in your jsp page

```
<form:form   commandName="user" modelAttribute="user">
```

I hope this will help you